# Analyze IIS Logfiles (like Google Analytics)

Tags: iis-7

Do you know a free good analyzer for IIS 7 Logfiles?

I want to make charts like google analytics, but locally!

I'm looking for a Windows tool WITHOUT CYGWIN and WITHOUT PERL :-)

Can you help me?

br,
knom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a reference..

PIWIK is the way to go!!

Google Analytics like tool, installable on your custom server!

Use [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/) for simple installation.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Indihiang](http://indihiang.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Try LogParser:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en

Lets you query log files in a SQL like language, very useful tool.